# Function Repeating Itself Even After Returning

Tags: java

I am making a Tic-Tac-Toe game with a computer player. However, whenever I call the computer's `makeMove` method, the computer continues to play without the user being able to do anything. Just to be sure that the function stopped, I made it return after each move, but it still plays the entire game without the user's input.

Here are the relevant parts:

`Board` Class:

```
public String addToBoard(char c, int square) {
        if (!spaceFull(board, square)) {
            int[] coords = getRowAndColumn(square);
            //System.out.println("[" + coords[0] + "][" + coords[1] + "]");
            board[coords[0]][coords[1]] = c;
            return "VALID";
        } else {
            System.out.println("Space Is Occupied");
            return "OCCUPIED";
        }
    }
public boolean spaceFull(char[][] b, int square) {
        return (twoDimenToOneDimen(b).get(square - 1) == 'X' || twoDimenToOneDimen(b).get(square - 1) == 'O');
    }
```

`Computer Class`

```
public void makeMove() {
        int square;
        //Checks For Any Winning Computer Moves
        System.out.println("Here");
        if ((square = nextMoveWinCheck(playerChar)) != 0) {
            board.addToBoard(playerChar, square);
            return;
            //Checks For Any Opponent Winning Moves
        } else if ((square = nextMoveWinCheck(opponentChar)) != 0) {
            board.addToBoard(playerChar, square);
            return;
        } else {
            //Checks If Computer Has First Move
            if (boardEmpty()) {
                board.addToBoard(playerChar, 9);
                return;
            } else {
                //Moves Into Opposite Corner if Bottom Corner is Occupied By Itself
                if (!board.spaceFull(board.board,1) && board.board[2][2] == playerChar) {
                    board.addToBoard(playerChar, 1);
                    return;
                    //Move Into Center If Second Move or Possible
                } else if (!board.spaceFull(board.board,5)) {
                    board.addToBoard(playerChar, 5);
                    return;
                } else if ((square = emptyCorner()) != 0) {
                    board.addToBoard(playerChar, square);
                    return;
                } else {
                    board.addToBoard(playerChar, randomEmptySpot());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want the full code, it's:

- [Computer](https://pastebin.com/B8LVdH7H)
- [Board](https://pastebin.com/ze0gCVei)
- [Player](https://pastebin.com/sA9jKbM2)
- [Tic-Tac-Toe Main Class](https://pastebin.com/uwjdurwY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in your class `Computer`. On line 57, you assign board.board to tempBoard. However tempBoard still holds the reference to the object board.board, so whatever modifications you make there is reflected on the actual board. To resolve this, COPY the board values to tempboard:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/clonetwodimensionalarray.htm